# Show hide groups based on dropdown

Tags: javascript

I have the following Html FORM with Javascript.  I want to show certain fields depending on what the user has chosen. Eg. If user select 'group 1' from dropdown I want to only show first group with its fields. Similar for selection 2 and 3.

Everything seem to be showing the groups and its fields associated correctly but when SAVE it does not save all the fields. I am not getting any errors or anything. When complete all the fields Only Group 1 and last group gets saved. Everything else gets ignored.

Removing the Javascript Code works fine. So it's not related to how I am saving the data.

Can anyone have a look please? thank you!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $('#Attending').on('change', function () {
            if (this.value == '1') {
                $("#grp1").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#grp1").hide();
            }

            if (this.value == '2') {
                $("#grp2").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#grp2").hide();
            }

            if (this.value == '3') {
                $("#grp3").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#grp3").hide();
            }

        });
    });
</script>

<body>
<select id='Attending'>
<option value="">Select One</option>
<option value="1">Group 1</option>
<option value="2">Group 2</option>
<option value="3">Group 3</option>
</select>
<div style='display:none;' id='grp1'>First Group<br/>&nbsp;
    <br/>&nbsp;
    <input type='text' class='text' name='FirtName1' value size='20' />
    <input type='text' class='text' name='LastName1' value size='20' />
    <br/>
</div>
    <div style='display:none;' id='grp2'>Second Group<br/>&nbsp; 
    <br/>&nbsp;
    <input type='text' class='text' name='FirtName1' value size='20' />
    <input type='text' class='text' name='LastName1' value size='20' />
    <br/>

    <input type='text' class='text' name='FirtName2' value size='20' /> 
    <input type='text' class='text' name='LastName2' value size='20' />
    <br/>
</div>        
    <div style='display:none;' id='grp3'>Third Group<br/>&nbsp; 
    <br/>&nbsp;
    <input type='text' class='text' name='FirtName1' value size='20' />
    <input type='text' class='text' name='LastName1' value size='20' /> 

    <input type='text' class='text' name='FirtName2' value size='20' /> 
    <input type='text' class='text' name='LastName2' value size='20' /> 

    <input type='text' class='text' name='FirtName3' value size='20' /> 
    <input type='text' class='text' name='LastName3' value size='20' />
    <br/>
    <br/>
</div>
</body>
```

----- UPDATE ----
Controller Code

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id, Attending,FirtName1,LastName1,FirtName2,LastName2,FamilyFName3,FirtName3,LastName3")] Family  Family_Reg)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Test.Add(Family_Reg);
                db.SaveChanges(); 
                return RedirectToAction("Home");
            }

            return View(Family_Reg);
        }
```

Comment: `but when SAVE it does not save all the fields` - you've not shown us any code associated with "saving" anything. Is there some server-side logic associated wit the saving? What language is it? You've posted a client-side question.

Comment: I didn't show any SAVE code because remove the above Javascript Code works fine. My issue is not related to how I am saving the data. I am sure my javascript code is wrong.

Comment: Your javascript works perfectly well (http://jsfiddle.net/trd5tzfy/). Did you step through your server-side code to see what the problem is with this javascript in place?

Comment: Correct. The code hides/shows the fields correctly on the server as well. It is possible that the way I am repeating the same fields  on Group3 is conflicting? eg FirstName2,LastName2 is in Group 2 and also in Group 3.

Comment: Without knowing your server-side code it's impossible to answer that!

Comment: ok. I have updated my post. Create() controller added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92875/discussion-between-ceci-and-jamiec).